# How to stream data from a python function to parquet file?

Tags: python, streaming, parquet, python-polars

I have a python file that does some operation on a list of files. The resulting dataframe is like 6 GB so I need to use a database or compress it with parquet. The thing is, the data gets generated from the function so I want to know how to stream batches of the data into a parquet file. What I have found on SO is taking a data set that's already created and breaking it up and sending to Parquet. I am also primarily using Polars not Pandas, so if anyone has any suggestions from there that'd be great.

```py
from time import sleep


def min_and_max(x: list[int]) -> tuple[int, int]:
    sleep(30)  # simuluating an expensive operation
    return (min(x), max(x))


numbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

for num in numbers:
    print(min_and_max(num))
    # I need a write_parquet function here.
    # Saving the results in a list or another data structure 
    # is taking too much memory.
```

Comment: Have you tried map_batches with element_wise

Comment: @DeanMacGregor No I only tried map_elements. Let me try that

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I am not sure I see an `element_wise` in the documentation. Did you mean `pl.element()`?

Comment: https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_batches.html#polars.Expr.map_batches the `is_elementwise` parameter

Comment: You can write in chunks using ParquetWriter https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html

Comment: @0x26res so would I use the record batch function? I think that's where my confusion is coming from. Like doing a for item in file_list: do_operate then write(record_batch) with some predefined schema that gets sent as an input

Comment: It's hard to tell without a reproducible example.

Comment: @0x26res I added an example. What I am doing exactly is working with images, but the return values and the sleep function simulate the key components in my actual example (slow process and multiple return types). So I just want to know how to store the results after one iteration of the loop. It will be slow but I would like to do something like this compared to a database because I am using Polars and it supports Apache Arrow.

Comment: @0x26res I found a solution. Posting below

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with that was Polars-esque. It takes advantage of the fact that the `write_parquet` function is making a call to the Pyarrow parquet package in the backend. Without complicating things, I will use my dummy example, but just know you can

```py
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep


# This part about the file path is not that relevant - just including for completeness
filepath = Path.cwd()
print(f"Dataframe will be saved here: {filepath}")


def min_and_max(x: list[int]) -> list[list[pl.Series]]:
    sleep(30)  # simuluating an expensive operation
    return [
        [pl.Series("min", min(x), dtype=pl.UInt8)], 
        [pl.Series("max", max(x), dtype=pl.UInt8)]
    ] # need to put all the return values in a nested list of lists


numbers = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

for i, v in enumerate(numbers):
    pl.from_records(
        min_and_max(numbers[i]), schema=["min", "max"]
    ).write_parquet(
        file=f"{filepath / "num_file"_i}.parquet", 
        compression="zstd", 
        compression_level=20, # experiment with this - see docs
        use_pyarrow=True
    )
```

There is a pyarrow_options that allows you to add other options. This incrementally creates the parquet files and sends them to a parquet file that you specify.